# How to stack multiple features of different shapes in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

What is a better way to do the following codeblock? I want to create a 1d array for each scene containing features a-e to eventually have the shape: `m x n` if `m` is the number of scenes and `n` is the combined length of all the features.

The shape of features a-d is unknown and can be different from each other. For example feature `a` could have shape `100 x 3 x 3 x 5` while feature `b` could have shape `30 x 4`. Feature `e` is simply a boolean.

```py
inputs = []
for scene in scenes:
    inp = np.concatenate((
              scene['a'].flatten(), 
              scene['b'].flatten(), 
              scene['c'].flatten(), 
              scene['d'].flatten(), 
              [scene['e'] == True]))
    inputs.append(inp)
inputs = torch.FloatTensor(inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say we know `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` are the only attributes in each scene ( so they're accessible by `scene.keys()`. Then, the following code works:

```py
output = np.vstack(
    np.hstack(map(lambda x: np.array(x).flatten(), s.values())) for s in scenes
)

inputs = torch.FloatTensor(output)
```

In order to test that, I created a scene generator function that creates dictionaries similar to what you mentioned and synthetically create 10 scenes:

```py
import numpy as np

def scense_generator():
    scene = dict()
    scene['a'] = np.random.random((100, 3, 3, 5))
    scene['b'] = np.random.random((30, 4))
    scene['c'] = np.random.random((15, 15, 2))
    scene['d'] = np.random.random((2, 2, 2))
    scene['e'] = True
    return scene

scenes = [scense_generator() for _ in range(10)]

output = np.vstack(
    np.hstack(map(lambda x: np.array(x).flatten(), s.values())) for s in scenes
)

print(output.shape)
# (10, 5079)
```